# Does "DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All" allow granting admin consent?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

In MS Graph, some delegated permissions need "Admin Consent" and some just need user consent.

For example, the delegated permission `User.Read.All` requires admin consent.  But the delegated permission `User.ReadBasic.All` does not need admin consent.  (But it would still need user consent.)

[image: Screenshot of permissions discussed above]

I know that `DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All` allows the application to grant consent on behalf of the user.  But I don't know if it can grant "Admin Consent".

Can an application with `DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All` grant "Admin Consent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All` allows a principal to grant admin consent for `Delegated` permissions only

`AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` allows a principal to grant admin consent for `Application` permissions

There are examples on how to do so with the MS Graph API and MS Graph PowerShell here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=ms-powershell

**MS Graph PowerShell Example**

```
# The object ID of your Enterprise Application
$servicePrincipalObjectId = ""

# This is the object ID of the Enterprise Application for Microsoft Graph
$graphId = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id

# Permissions to grant consent to, space separated
$scopes = "User.Read.All Directory.Read.All"

$params = @{
    ClientId    = $servicePrincipalObjectId
    ConsentType = "AllPrincipals"
    ResourceId  = $graphId
    Scope       = $scopes
}

New-MgOauth2PermissionGrant -BodyParameter $params
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The *DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All* permission allows creating any [**oauth2PermissionGrant**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-1.0) (a delegated permission grant) including one where the **consentType** property is set to "AllPrincipals" (i.e. on behalf of all users), and regardless of whether the granted delegated permissions are configured to require admin consent or not.

This grants the **Directory.Read.All** and **User.Read.All** delegated permissions on behalf of all users:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants

{
  "clientId": "...",
  "resourceId": "...",
  "principalType": "AllPrincipals",
  "scope": "Directory.Read.All User.Read.All"
}
```

This grants the same permissions, but only on behalf of one user:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants

{
  "clientId": "...",
  "resourceId": "...",
  "principalType": "Principal",
  "principalId": "{user-id}"
  "scope": "Directory.Read.All User.Read.All"
}
```